# How to Post a Custom Named Method in Web Api ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am new in Web Api. I am Create a web Api Controller with custom named actions. I am calling this from a WPF client using HttpClient. But I get an error 
**response status code does not indicate success 404 (Not Found)**

Here Is My Web Api Controller :

```
public class ActivationController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IActivationUnit _activationUnit;

    public ActivationController()
    {
        _activationUnit = new ActivationUnit();
    }

    //  api/activation/GetAllActivisionInformations
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllActivationInformations(string username)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _activationUnit.ActivationRepository.GetActivationInformations(username));
    }

    // api/activation/NewLicense
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostNewLicense(LicenseMetadata licenseMetadata)
    {
        bool isSuccess = _activationUnit.ActivationRepository.NewLicense(licenseMetadata.Username, licenseMetadata.ActivisionInformation);
        if (isSuccess)
        {
            try
            {
                _activationUnit.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(isSuccess ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, isSuccess);
    }
}
```

My Routing is:

```
 //   Route for POST method
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "DefaultApi2",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );

 //   Route  GET method

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "DefaultApi1",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

My Client Code is :

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:42471");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
       new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 var licenseMetadata = new LicenseMetadata
      {
         ActivisionInformation = new ActivisionInformation(),
         Username = "UserName"
       };

 var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/activation/NewLicense", licenseMetadata);
 try
   {
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      MessageBox.Show("Success");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

> When I send Request to server using HttpClient then i get **response status code does
>   not indicate success 404 (Not Found)**

I was try to change url "api/activation/newlicense" to "api/activation/PostNewLicense" but in this case I get

> **response status code does not indicate success 500 (Internal Server Error)** form HttpClient

Where I am doing wrong. I am already spend two days for it.

I am using :
           Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4, MVC 4, Windows 8, IIS 8

Comment: In your current code `PostNewLicense` is your action name, as per my answer you don't need the `Post` prefix if you alter the routes (you've mixed two different ideas). In regards to your 500 error, that's your code throwing an exception, so just attach a debugger and set some breakpoints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use the default implementation of having a Get/Post in your action names, and instead want to call methods, adjust your routes as you have (just the first one, don't have a 2nd one for get), and **stop** using the `Get` and `Post` prefixes.

Route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionNameApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
};
```

In your Controller:

```
public class ActivationController : ApiController
{
    // .. other code ..

    // api/Activation/NewLicense
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewLicense(LicenseMetadata licenseMetadata)
    {
        // .. rest of your code ..
    }
}
```

Personally I don't like the default implementation, unless you are trying to create a REST API. The way it works is that you can have `GetFooBar` and `PostBarBaz`, it doesn't matter what you have after `Get` and `Post`. For my purposes I always override the route as above.

Comment: Nice post. There is one code error: the last "};" should be ");" on the MapHttpRoute.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great question.  Nobody has answered it yet.  Here is the answer.  You must decorate the Post method with the Route expected like this.

Here is an example of mine that I finally got to work.
My Post Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/excel/createauditfile")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateAuditFile(Request<AuditFile> request)
    {
        Response<FileInfo> response = new Response<FileInfo>();

        try
        {
            response.Result = _repository.CreateAuditFile(request.Parameter);
            response.IsSuccessStatusCode = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.IsSuccessStatusCode = false;
            response.exception = ex;
        }
        return Ok<Response<FileInfo>>(response);
    }
```

My service call Method:

```
    public FileInfo CreateAuditFile(AuditFile auditFile)
    {
        Request<AuditFile> request = new Request<AuditFile>();
        request.Parameter = auditFile;

        response = Client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/excel/createauditfile", request).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<FileInfo>>(data);

            if (!responseData.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Exception ex = responseData.exception;
                throw ex;
            }

            return responseData.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("An unexpected Service Exception has Happened.  Please contact your administrator.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default route should work for your action methods. Web API will pick the right action method based on the http verb.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The controller represent a resource that you can get by sending a get request and create by issuing a post request to it.

When posting you should use the URL:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/activation", licenseMetadata);
```

A 500 response often means that your api method was called and threw an exception.
I would set a breakpoint in the first line of my web api methods to check for this.
I would also recommend getting fiddler to better see the requests and responses.

Comment: This assumes the OP wants to use the default 'magic' implementation that uses the verb in the method name to work things out, but the OP specifically wants to use the Method name as part of the route when using Web API